# 0 limit point of spectrum of completely continuous operator $H\to H$

Tags: general-topology, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* (p. 475 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that 0 is an [accumulation point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition) for the spectrum of a completely continuous operator $A:H\to H$ where $A$ is a Hilbert space.

I know that the spectrum of $A$ is (at most) countable, as Kolmogorov-Fomin's shows, contains eigenvalues only and always contains 0. Moreover, I [know](http://librarum.org/book/10022/127) that, for any $\rho>0$, $A$ has only a finite number of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues of absolute value greater than $\rho$, which implies that its eigenvalues can be ordered in a way such that $|\lambda_1|\ge|\lambda_2|\ge\ldots$

Please correct me if I am wrong, but, from these facts, I deduce that no eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ such that $|\lambda_k|>0$ can be an accumulation point of $\sigma(A)$. Nevertheless, I do not see why 0 necessarily is an accumulation point. In particular, Kolmogorov-Fomin's does not rule out the possibility that $\sigma(A)$ can be finite and I do not see how a finite set of complex numbers can have an accumulation point. Thank you for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on p.475 Kolmogorov-Fomin says: "$\dots0$ is the only **possible** accumulation point for the sequence $\{\mu_n\}\dots$"

Kolmogorov-Fomin does not exclude the possibility that $\sigma(A)$ is finite and there is no accumulation point for $\sigma(A).$

Comment: Missed "возможная". Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста )